# How to call original jQuery function if jQuery functions are overriden by another script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, inheritance, prototype

I am working on a website as a vendor and the site's javascript overrides jQuery functions like "empty", "text", "append" etc. Something like :

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  text: function(value) {...},
  empty: function(value) {...},
...
})
```

Now, my javascript library uses the same jQuery and uses these jQuery functions. Due to this, these jQuery functions behave abnormally in my library.

Is there a way to prevent calling these functions and use original jquery functions instead.

P.S. : I do not want to include the jQuery library again.

Comment: I think you are out of luck then. Without loading the library again, you are doomed to use those functions, unless you reimplement the jQuery implementation. You did say you are a vendor, so bringing this up and asking them to undo what they did, is also out of the question. My advice, is to use pure javascript then. You will end up much better off as a vendor with this skillset.

Comment: _"P.S. : I do not want to include the jQuery library again."_ I think that's your best bet, with `noConflict`.

Comment: That's what I thought. My library currently uses jQuery and turning it into pure javascript also doesn't seem as a solution with the time I have. In the worst case I will probably have to load the library again.

Comment: Maybe iframe good save you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "as a vendor"? You have only three choices: a) don't use jQuery b) bring your own jQuery packaged into your library c) require a compatible jQuery to be loaded before your library. Whoever is using your lib fails to comply with c), and that's his fault - not yours. You can offer them help fixing their problem that breaks jQuery, or you choose another approach.